# CKeditor not working on template CreateVIew in Django

Tags: django

I just install Ckeditor and I try to add something new. I can see the Ckeditor is showing but I can not render on the template Create View. Anyone can give me some advice
Model.py

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

 class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')
```

Form.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'author',
                  'category', 'body')

        widgets = {  # add styling
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form- 
 control'}),
            'title_tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form- 
 control'}),
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 
            'value': '', 'id': 'elder'}),

            'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list, 
            attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Views.py

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
```

Template

```
 <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.media }}
            {{ form.as_p }}
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Can you show configuration?